# client.GetServer() deprecated , how can I fixed it?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, mongodb-.net-driver

My block of code:

```
   public StudentsUnitOfWork()
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBConectionString"];
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBDatabaseName"];
            _database = server.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        }
```

VS 2015 I get `client.GetServer() deprecated , how can I fixed it?`

and after I change to use this:

```
public StudentsUnitOfWork()
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBConectionString"];
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
           // var server = client.GetServer();
            var databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBDatabaseName"];
            _database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        }
```

it say, cannot implicit convert type ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my entire context and it works fine for me:

```
public class MyContext
{
    public const string COLLECTION_NAME = "CollectionName";

    private static readonly IMongoClient _client;
    private static readonly IMongoDatabase _database;
    static MyContext()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBConectionString"];
        _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBDatabaseName"];
        _database = _client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    }

    public IMongoClient Client
    {
        get { return _client; }
    }

    public IMongoCollection<TDocument> DocumentType =>
        _database.GetCollection<TDocument>(COLLECTION_NAME);
}
```